# Aggregating a time field in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a line graph in Power BI, to show the completion time over the last 30 days for a given process.

My data is as follows;

```
ProcessName        EndDate               EndTime
Partner            01/12/2020            06:05:00
Partner            02/12/2020            06:37:00
Partner            03/12/2020            06:24:00
```

I'm trying to plot the EndTime in a line graph, to show where it peaks for a given day, however Power BI will only let me Count EndTime, where I want to SUM/MAX the EndTime and therefore aggregate it, is this achievable?

Line graph example;

Axis: EndDate

Legend: ProcessName

Values: MAX(EndTime)

Comment: Have you tried writing a measure? I think MAX should work.